# Kaa: Is there a step by step video demo on how to setup Data collection Demos?

Tags: kaa

I'm stuck at the bundleId=datacollection_demos. I ended up entering into the Adminitration UI and I think I'm supposed to setup the schemas for Data collection and then there are lots of options there and I'm not sure which to choose and wht to do next. I tried to find step by step guides online but most of it are over the steps I'm stuck in...

Comment: go step by step : https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a step-by-step tutorial on each Kaa feature (including Data Collection) in the Kaa 0.10 Sandbox. Also, the 'Your first Kaa application' guide in the Kaa documentation resembles the Data Collection demo and its tutorials.